# Deploy conditional charts based on kubeVersion - Helm

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, devops, kubernetes-helm

I have two helm charts with versions : `1.3 & 4.0.` I'm looking for ways to deploy charts in CI CD process, based on cluster kubeVerion, if `kubeVersion > 1.19 then v4.0 else v1.3.` How can I achieve this type of conditional option in Charts.yaml, is there any way for this?

Thanks in advance.

Update: Helm v3 in use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible since Helm has some built-in objects.

I think you are probably looking for [.Capabilities.KubeVersion.Minor](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/builtin_objects/).

You just need to put an `if` at the top of your `template`, then if the version doesn't match, Helm won't deploy it.

eg:

```
{{- if ge .Capabilities.KubeVersion.Minor 19 }}
---
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
   name: "{{ app_v4 }}"
...
...
{{- end }}
```

If you have both `templates` in the same file, you can use `else` to improve the logic. [Template Functions and Pipelines](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/).

Comment: In my case, I had to write `{{- if ge (int .Capabilities.KubeVersion.Minor) 24 }}` otherwise I was getting the error `error calling ge: incompatible types for comparison`

Answer (score 0):

The helm charts are not "logic" defining elements. They are just artifacts or a piece of "blob" which can exist in one version or the other (e.g. one for 1.3 and one for 4.0).

It should be up to your CI/CD system and pipeline logic to check the Kubernetes version and then download and deploy the right chart/blob/file.

A blob or a file its-self won't be able to decide on logics, that's what a helm chart is eventually